# Loading an Object with getter and setter

Tags: java, object, methods, getter-setter

I'm new in Java Objects and my question is:

- I have the class Person
- I am creating a new Object person5
- I'm setting the ID to 5
- Now I want that in my Object person5 are all information the person with the 
  ID 5 has, are in the object person5
- Then i want to get the age of the person5

When I debugged my code only the ID was set to 5 all other variables were null.

```
Person person5 = new Person();
person5.setID(5);
person5.getAge();


@Id @Column(name = "ID") 
private Integer id; 

@Column(name = "AGE") 
private Integer age; 

public Integer getId() { 
return id; 
} 

public void setId(Integer id) { 
this.id = id; 
} 

public Integer getAge() { 
return age; 
} 

public void setAge(Integer age) { 
this.age = age; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me?

Comment: do you want to retrieve information from database?

Comment: yes the information is from a database

Comment: Ah. So you need to learn about JDBC and/or JPA. This is much too broad. Find a tutorial and read.

Comment: so you can retrieve data by using sql: select * from persontable where id=5

Comment: is there a other possibility than using sql?

Comment: Flyweight objects, eh. You need to implement `setID` in a way that would read required data from database. I wouldn't _really_ advise doing that though, because then that object probably takes on more responsibility than it strictly requires. I'd rather you made some `PersonRepository` class with `findById` method on it, that would return a `Person`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Person person5 = new Person();
```

You created a new Person

```
person5.setID(5);
```

You decided that the ID of the newly created person will be 5.

```
person5.getAge();
```

Since you haven't explicitly told Java to change the age of the person from what was set by the constructor, it will tell you what it was told, which is **nothing**.

***Now I want that in my Object person5 are all information the person with the ID 5 has, is in the object person5***

At this point, Java knows nothing about which person5 you are talking about. If you want it to have all the attributes of a similar person, you'll have to tell Java to either set all those attributes into your object or create a new one using values (from DB presumably).

It is better to clear up doubts on OOPS before getting into deeper concepts like DB connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

1. You dont show us your getter and setter function
2. replace your code with 
   `Person person5 = new Person();
   person5.setID(5);
   person5.getAge();`
3. you didnt set an age for the person. neither in the constructor nor as `person5.setAge(X)`

this question is very common and you should visit some tutorial pages. stackoverflow isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using JPA. Then, the correct way of retrieving information from the database is not simply new-ing an object and setting the id, you would have to fetch it from the database, through `EntityManager`:

```
final Person person5 = em.find(Person.class, 5);
```